# Place Jlabel over another

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlabel, overlap

I am using netbeans.
I want to place one JLabel exactly over another JLabel (contained in a JPanel which is in turn in a JFrame).
Net beans just wont allow it and keeps repositioning the labels. I saw it allows this only in a Null layout for the panel. Netbeans by default uses group layout.
Is there a way to acheive this? Or must I use null layout?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing so?

Comment: No this is quite possible, as shown in this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10245045/1057230)

Answer (score 3):

1. use  [`OverlayLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/OverlayLayout.html)
2. set proper [`LayoutManager` to `JLabel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), then (now `JLabel` is contianer) put there another `JLabel`

Comment: +1 for OverlayLayout - [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/LayoutOverlaySample.htm)

Comment: @mKorbel Making JLabel a container is good. But since netbeans does not have such a layout, I must code by hand. Is there another way? (sorry not that this wasnt a good answer !)

Comment: not it wasn't in the case that you are GuiBuilder prisonier, you save 5minutes with many hours to fixing standard ideas somewhere hidden in setting for Swing Framework, or isn't possible, up to you

Answer (score 0):

Use layout manager to 'null', it would be helpful to you for setting your gui wherever you want.

Comment: Actually this advice goes the opposite of what you saying, regarding setting layout to `null`. Just read the first paragraph below the heading of [Absolute Positioning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html), that might can give you the idea :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. `Write click on the JFrame`
2. `Set Layout > Null Layout`

now you can place JLabel over another one.

Comment: use `Change order` to send back Jlabel